# How to loop over multiple arrays for a resource

Tags: arrays, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I want to create a resource for many regions, environments, apps, etc at once.
I'd like to do something like this:

```
param apps array = [
  'app1'
  'app2'
  'app3'
]

param environments array = [
  'alpha'
  'beta'
]

param regions array = [
  'ne'
  'we'
  'uks'
]


resource origin_group 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/origingroups@2021-06-01' = [ for region in regions: {
[ for env in environments: {
[ for app in apps: {
  parent: profiles_global_fd_name_resource
  name: '${env}-${region}-${app}-origin-group'
  properties: {
    loadBalancingSettings: {
      sampleSize: 4
      successfulSamplesRequired: 3
      additionalLatencyInMilliseconds: 50
    }
    healthProbeSettings: {
      probePath: '/'
      probeRequestType: 'HEAD'
      probeProtocol: 'Http'
      probeIntervalInSeconds: 100
    }
    sessionAffinityState: 'Disabled'
  }
}]
}]
}]
```

All docs mentioning nested loops talk about looping inside a resource to create many sub-resources. Not what I'm after. Perhaps another way would be to somehow merge all these arrays into a single array of objects of every possible iteration. Not sure where to start with that either.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not supported for the moment but it will (see [Is there plans to support nested loop on resources?](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/discussions/1280)).

**EDIT April 2023**

Bicep now supports [lambda functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-lambda). The `reduce` and `map` function could be use to generate all the possible combinations:

```bicep
param environments array = [ 'alpha', 'beta' ]
param regions array = [ 'ne', 'we', 'uks' ]
param apps array = [ 'app1', 'app2', 'app3' ]

// Create an array of env-region
var envRegions = reduce(environments, [], (cur, next) => concat(cur, map(regions, region => '${next}-${region}')))

// Add the app to the previously created array env-region-app
output envRegionApps array = reduce(envRegions, [], (cur, next) => concat(cur, map(apps, app => '${next}-${app}')))
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Using a little bit of math, you could achieve what you'd like (Not sure if you should):

```bicep
param environments array = [ 'alpha', 'beta' ]
param regions array = [ 'ne', 'we', 'uks' ]
param apps array = [ 'app1', 'app2', 'app3' ]

// Setting some variables for clarity
var envCount = length(environments)
var regionCount = length(regions)
var appCount = length(apps)

// Setting the total number of combination
var originGroupCount = envCount * regionCount * appCount

// Iterate all possible combinations
output originGroupNames array = [for i in range(0, originGroupCount): {
  name: '${environments[i / (regionCount * appCount) % envCount]}-${regions[i / appCount % regionCount]}-${apps[i % appCount]}-origin-group'
}]
```

this will output all possible combinations (I think) for origin group name.

Comment: It's a shame it's been an open issue for over a year but thank you for the link. Your solution is impressive and very welcome but for the sake of simplicity I think I'm going to fall back to terraform for this. Thanks