# Combine two arrays to create every possible combination with Azure Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I'm investigating using Bicep for setting up Azure resources. Is it possible to define the type of workload in one array and the environments in another, and then combining them to create a resource name for each combination? The concept of nested loop could to the trick, but I'm not sure if that would require creating custom Bicep modules to allow for the nesting.

E.g.

```
var environments = ['test','prod']
var workloads = ['workload1', 'workload2']

// Do combination work of the two arrays, resulting in:
//names = ['workload1-test', 'workload1-prod', 'workload2-test', 'workload2-prod']

// Loop over names and define resources
```

Comment: Ideally you would be able to loop multiple times but it s not yet supported. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72739394/4167200

Comment: Thank you, @Thomas! The answer seems to be what I was looking for, marking my question as a duplicate